# How can i create react-app with less node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have used `create-react-app <folder-name>` on my desktop and then it has generated a folder of 241 MB containing 1021 folders inside the `node_modules` folder.

My Udemy instructor used the same command but he got only a few folders in `node_modules`.

Please can anyone help me in getting rid of those unnecessary  folders.[Check it out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0mQL.png)

Comment: Are you concerned about your bundle size? Or are you adding node_modules to version control? Or is it simply to have less folders? Please explain the source of your concern...

Comment: i just want to add specific node_modules to my react application. but that command add 1021 folders which are making the application very heavy and even my editor is lagging.

Comment: If you wanted to cut down on the number of modules in node_modules, you could set up your React app from scratch. It's an excellent exercise to understand how all the pieces work.

Answer (score 1):

The size seems a bit too high for a fresh install, in my case a CRA takes about 120MB.

The modules you see are not unnecessary, they are part of create-react-app and have been chosen by the team as a general starting point (I'm not sure how your Udemy instructor has only a few folders after a fresh install, but the number of node_modules depends on the OS and the package manager used).

The main benefit of create-react-app is how quickly it gets you ready to code, but you lose customizability. If you want to get rid of all the modules you don't use you should either `eject` and remove them or ditch CRA altogether and make your own boilerplate.

Comment: thanks man, yeah my instructor only got 4-5 folders in that node_module folder...well thats ok.. but if i want to create another react project so should i again need to download the whole stuff ?

Comment: If your instructor indeed used `create-react-app`, I seriously doubt that it only added 4-5 folders in node_modules.

Comment: By adding babel or webpack alone  you already had more than 50+ folders